# How to filter orders on my accounts page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added the search field on the My Account > Order page and would like to filter the orders by using the order number. Here is my current code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 10, 1);
function custom_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query($array) {
    if ( isset($_GET['ordernumber']) ){
         $ordernumber = $_GET['ordernumber'];
         $array['post__in'] = array( $ordernumber );
    }
    return $array;
}
```

`$_GET['ordernumber']` contains the order number in the request. But for some reason this code doesn't allow to display any orders on that page.

Comment: Just tested your code and it works perfectly.! Now as displayed orders are related to the current customer (user ID), maybe you are no searching with the right order number.

Comment: Thanks! Something must be due to conflict etc.